# Using datePicker for multiple textfields in iOS swift

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift4, uidatepicker

I am having 4 textFields where I have to set `fromDate`, `fromTime` and `toDate`, `toTime` for a `userServiceBooking`. Now, I need to fill these textFields with `UIDatePicker` and I am not able to show the text and I don't know why; maybe I am doing it totally wrong...

I am posting the code that I've tried and please someone look into it and tell how to do it.

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ConfirmRequestViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var fromDateTF: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var toDateTF: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var fromTimeTF: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var toTimeTF: UITextField!
  var datePicker = UIDatePicker()
  var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  var toolBar = UIToolbar()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 }

 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField == fromDateTF {

            datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
            fromDateTF.inputView = datePicker

            fromDateTF.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

            toolBar.sizeToFit()

            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped))
            toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
            fromDateTF.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        }
        if textField == toDateTF {

            datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
            toDateTF.inputView = datePicker

            toolBar.sizeToFit()

            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped))
            toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
            toDateTF.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        }
        if textField == fromTimeTF {

            datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
            fromTimeTF.inputView = datePicker

            toolBar.sizeToFit()

            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped))
            toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
            fromTimeTF.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        }
        if textField == toTimeTF {

            datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
            toTimeTF.inputView = datePicker

            toolBar.sizeToFit()

            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped))
            toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
            toTimeTF.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        }
    }

    @objc func doneButtonTapped(textField: UITextField) {

        if textField == fromDateTF {

            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
            fromDateTF.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        }
        if textField == toDateTF {

            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
            toDateTF.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        }
        if textField == fromTimeTF {

            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
            fromTimeTF.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        }
        if textField == toTimeTF {

            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
            toTimeTF.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        }
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
 }
```

Comment: this method is called or not doneButtonTapped

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Thanks for the fast reply. Yes, it is calling the method doneButtonTapped() but it is not going into the if condition for whichever the textfield I'm currently editing..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fromDateTF.inputView    = datePicker
    toDateTF.inputView      = datePicker
    fromTimeTF.inputView    = datePicker
    toTimeTF.inputView      = datePicker

    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped))
    toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
    fromDateTF.inputAccessoryView   = toolBar
    toDateTF.inputAccessoryView     = toolBar
    fromTimeTF.inputAccessoryView   = toolBar
    toTimeTF.inputAccessoryView     = toolBar
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == fromDateTF {
            datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        }
        if textField == toDateTF {
            datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        }
        if textField == fromTimeTF {
            datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
        }
        if textField == toTimeTF {
            datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
        }
    }

@objc func doneButtonTapped() {
    if fromDateTF.isFirstResponder {
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        fromDateTF.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    }
    if toDateTF.isFirstResponder {
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        toDateTF.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    }
    if fromTimeTF.isFirstResponder {
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
        fromTimeTF.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    }
    if toTimeTF.isFirstResponder {
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
        toTimeTF.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    }
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: it will validate all textfields

Comment: @Anbu.karthik, sorry I am not getting you.

Comment: @Kuldeep This worked very well. Thanks bro. Only change is instead of `if textfield == fromDateTF{ code }` I have to write `if fromDateTF.isFirstResponder{ code }`. So no need of textField parameter for method `doneButtonPressed()`.

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla, instead of creating `doneButton` multiple times, create it once.

Comment: @Kuldeep Yeah, Sorry for not mentioning it, I did it. But, I am just telling that the main reason it didn't work is because of not using `.isFirstResponder`..